# Restrictive Prefix Slug in Laravel route matching pattern

Tags: regex, laravel, routes, pattern-matching

My problem, using this route definition:

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/create/{caller?}', 'create')
   ->name('elot.create')
   ->where('caller', '([sh|br]+-[0-9]+)');
```

*http://localhost/create/shxyz-1234 -- works*

*http://localhost/create/brxyz-1234 -- works*

But i don't want things happen like this. I want ONLY that Match like this

http://localhost/create/sh-26627 --  not `shxyz-1234`

http://localhost/create/br-1525 --  not `brxyz-1234`

Comment: ([sh|br]-[0-9]+) Try to remove plus in the middle

Comment: You are using square brackets, which denotes a character class. I think you meant to use a grouping like `\b(?:sh|br)-[0-9]+\b` https://regex101.com/r/dkYmWn/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries `\b` to prevent partial word matches and use a grouping instead of square brackets, which means a character class.

That grouping does not have to be repeated, as the alternation `|` matches one of the alternatives. As you are only matching, you can use a non capture group, denoted as `(?:`

```
\b(?:sh|br)-[0-9]+\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dkYmWn/1).